# Which method can call native API faster than the others?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++-cli

Suppose that i have three pieces of code that can call a native Win API as following:

**1) compiling mode: `/clr`**

```
#pragma unmanaged
void finc(){
::MessageBox(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box",0);
}
#pragma managed
```

**2) compiling mode: `/clr:safe`**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet::Auto)]
int MessageBox(IntPtr, String^ text, String^ caption, unsigned int type);
int main(){
MessageBox(IntPtr::Zero, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box",0);
}
```

**3) compiling mode: `/clr`**

```
void finc(){
::MessageBox(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box",0);
}
```

Which code can give the best performance (fastest) in calling the Win API function, and `why`?

Comment: ho god, managed c++ ! my eyes are bleeding...

Comment: those are calls to Win32 rather than to the native api. I'd be astonished if it ever made a real difference to performance. I'd worry about something else if I were you.

Comment: Note: The OP uses the term "native API" to distinguish between the Windows API (unmanaged) and the .NET Framework (managed). It does not refer to [the Native API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API) used internally by the Windows operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@csl is right that you should profile in order to find out what parts of your code need optimizing.  And you should profile again after optimizing, to make sure it helped.

That said, using the profiler as an oracle is not an effective way to optimize.  Once you've identified the code that causes performance issues, understanding where those issues come from is much more likely to lead you to improvements than blindly making changes and hoping the profiler will tell you it got faster.

One of the most fundamental rules of optimization (after profile first) is that if approach B does all the same work approach A does, it won't be faster.  It's quite possible to fit additional work into the same time, if the CPU is wasting time waiting for data that's not in cache, but you can't get the same results faster by doing them the same way.

So first thing I notice about your example, aside from the fact that the MessageBox API does far more work than setting up a function call, so your savings will be insignificant, is that some things MUST be done in order to call MessageBox.

- The arguments must be pushed according to the calling convention.
- The function must be called.

This leads to the following conclusion:

*It is not possible to make code faster than the simple unmanaged program:*

```
#include <windows.h>
void func( void )
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", MB_OK);
}

int main( void )
{
    func();
}
```

After the optimizer inlines the call, which it surely will, the native optimizer is quite good, this program will not do anything except preparing the argument list and calling the function, right?

Well, that's not true.  The C++ runtime library will do a bunch of setup, which is unnecessary for this example.  You could get a huge improvement by using a custom entry-point, but it would only look like `func` got faster, really the changes came from code that's hidden from you by the compiler.

Even if you eliminate the C++ runtime library, you're still left with a small amount of overhead: The OS loader resolving imports, which leads to another detail: here the call is made using a function pointer, not an immediate address.  However, modern CPU branch prediction removes the cost of this indirection.

That's really going to be the theme, btw, management of code added behind the scenes.

Anyway, next case.  This code will not be faster, but I doubt it will be slower either, at least *after main starts running*:

```
// compile with /clr
#include <windows.h>

void func( void )
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", MB_OK);
}

int main( void )
{
    func();
}
```

This is a mixed-mode assembly using C++ interop.  The C++ compiler can no longer inline the call to `func`, but optimization is now the responsibility of the JIT.  The C++/CLI compiler also turns off code security in this case, you can't even load a mixed-mode assembly without permission to run unmanaged code, so it won't be checked on every call.

This program will be much slower than the first, because the runtime library initialization got massively more complicated by the introduction of .NET.  But after the JIT runs, the function call will be identical to the first, the per-call cost of `func` is identical.

Let's look at another case from the question:

```
// compile with /clr
#include <windows.h>

#pragma managed(push, off)
void func( void )
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", 0);
}
#pragma managed(pop)

int main( void )
{
    func();
}
```

We still have to load the .NET runtime, we still have to JIT, we still have to actually set up arguments and call `MessageBox`.  So this *cannot be faster* than the examples above.  Since the implementation of `func` is not managed code, the JIT cannot inline it.  But now it's possible for the C++ compiler to do so, since `func` is no longer a managed function that has to be left alone.  If the optimizer inlines `func`, we've got identical performance to the previous case, otherwise we have one extra function call.  Really not something you should be worrying about.

Next case:

```
// compile with /clr:pure
#include <windows.h>

void func( void )
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", MB_OK);
}

int main( void )
{
    func();
}
```

Now we no longer have a mixed-mode assembly and we no longer have C++ interop.  Instead the compiler will generate a matching p/invoke signature (why would you write p/invoke signatures by hand?).  As a result it is not the OS loader resolving the import, but .NET's runtime.  And now that import address can be available to the JIT, which theoretically could encode the fixed-up address directly into the call instruction and avoid the function pointer, although we already learned that branch prediction makes this difference moot.  But p/invoke is designed for safety, not speed, so what you actually get is some extra stack checking around the call to make sure the p/invoke signature was right.

Bottom line: this version is definitely slower, but not enough to be significant.

Let's make one TINY change:

```
// compile with /clr:safe
#include <windows.h>

void func( void )
{
    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", MB_OK);
}

int main( void )
{
    func();
}
```

Ok, asked the assembly to be verifiable.  All the p/invoke stuff is the same as `/clr:pure`, but this code is no longer restricted to running in a trusted environment.  So the code access security checks cannot be turned off.  Security checks shortcut when the environment is fully trusted, and this example application hasn't turned on partial trust, so it's not going to make much difference.  In a real-world scenario with a C++/CLI assembly loaded into a larger .NET application, the impact of security checks can be HUGE because each one requires a stack walk.  One way to mitigate this is with CAS assertions as close in the call stack as possible any time many p/invoke calls will be made in sequence, but running in partial trust WILL slow down your calls to native code.

```
// compile with /clr:safe
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet::Auto)]
int MessageBox(System::IntPtr, System::String^ text, System::String^ caption, unsigned type);

int main( void )
{
    MessageBox(System::IntPtr::Zero, "Hi all", "Win32 Message Box", 0);
}
```

This is example #2 from the question.  It is *miserably* slow by comparison, although still probably not enough to notice beside the cost of `MessageBox` itself.  The reason is that the user-provided p/invoke signature is badly suboptimal compared to the one the compiler could generate automatically using the header file.  Not only is `GetLastError` support missing, but the parameter type changed from `SByte*` to `System::String^`.  Now p/invoke has considerable work to do: allocating space that can't be moved by the garbage collector and copying the string content there.  To make matters even worse, `CharSet.Auto` means ANSI.  `System::String` is Unicode.  So P/Invoke needs to not only copy the string content, but perform Unicode -> ANSI conversion as well.

Again, for `MessageBox` the overhead is insignificant compared to the task.  But for other functions, like `glVertex2i` and `GetClassName`, extra work like copying arguments, Unicode <-> ANSI conversion, and CAS stackwalking can make or break performance.

Comment: great! thank you for all this information, it was an ideal answer, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Just test it by profiling.  Call a method 100k times, time it and print out the numbers for each test.

Comment: ... and write the results on this page to help others :)